# Correctly Solving equations containing ceiling and floor operations

Tags: functions, discrete-mathematics

Given the eaquation ($\forall x \in \{X_{in}, X_{out}, P, D, K, S\} : x\in \mathbb{Z}^+$):
$${X_{out}} = \left\lfloor {\frac{{X_{in}} + 2P - {D} ({K} - 1) - 1}{S}} + 1 \right\rfloor \tag{1}$$

Trying to find $P$ for two conditions:
$$
\begin{align*}
X_{out} &= X_{in} \tag{2a}\\
X_{out} &= \frac{X_{in}}{S} \tag{2b}
\end{align*}
$$

If the $\lfloor\circ\rfloor$ in equation $\text{(1)}$ is ignored, applying the conditions $\text{(2a)}$ and $\text{(2b)}$ respectively we get:
$$
\begin{align*}
P &= \frac{1}{2}\left[ (X_{in} - 1)(S - 1) + D(K - 1) \right] \tag{3a}\\
P &= \frac{D(K - 1) - (S - 1)}{2} \tag{3b}
\end{align*}
$$

Obviously these are not the correct solution. How to find the correct solutions? Equation $\text{(3b)}$ is agnostic to $X_{in}$, Does the correct solution have the same property?

Comment: Why $D$, $K$ and $S$ have subindices in $(3b)$?

Comment: That was a mistake. I will edit it.